# how to pass a criteria specific or filtered datasource to UITableview from another view?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

this question might be easy but i'm not sure how to do it.

i will like to show a tableview based on users criteria.

user have a checklist, when checked certain or multiple item, the array will check and inform user there is 3 item matching this criteria.

if user tapped on the button, it will push and show the 3 item in UItableview.

tutorial or sample code are appreciated..

thanks for reading

Comment: Please clarify your question...

Comment: filter tableview based on user selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load an `NSMutableArray` with the desired items based on the checklist, but adding items when the user checks something or removing objects when the user unchecks something. Call `array.count` to get the total number of items. Then pass this array to the `UITableView` as its data source.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply PengOne, this was what i was thinking to do... however the datasources only take in one criteria, i was thinking to get it done with predicate which will check all if it matched the criteria ? but is there a sample code for it ?

Answer (score 1):

Take an `array` of selected items,call a method,reload your `tableview` in this method, match your array data with cell text then increase any variable value. then just make an alert view and show the number of items using that variable.

If further any problem knock me.